# Return RGB values from Range.Interior.Color (or any other Color Property)

Tags: excel, vba, colors, rgb

I was trying to incrementally change the background color of a cell to black, and I found that the Range.Interior.Color method returns a Long which is seemingly arbitrary.  Looking at the documentation on MSDN, there is nearly nothing about what this number represents.  Is there a way to return the RGB value from this long.  I effectively need the opposite of the RGB(red, green, blue) function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

There is no built in functionality for this.  You must write your own function.

**Long Answer:**

The long that is returned from the Interior.Color property is a decimal conversion of the typical hexidecimal numbers that we are used to seeing for colors in html e.g. "66FF66".  Additionally the constant xlNone (-4142) can be passed to set cell to have no color in the background, however such cells are marked white `RGB(255, 255, 255)` from the `Get` property.  Knowing this, we can write a function that returns one or all of the appropriate RGB values.

Luckily, a kind Mr. Allan Wyatt has done just that here!

[Determining the RGB Value of a Color](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010180_Determining_the_RGB_Value_of_a_Color.html)

Answer (score 52):

That "arbitrary" number is a mathematical combination of the RGB values (B*256^2 + G*256 + R) and a conversion of the hex color value to a decimal number (base 16 to base 10), depending on which way you want to look at it. Just different bases. Below is the method I use in the XLAM addin file I wrote for Excel. This method has come in handy many times. I have included the documentation in my addin file.

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'   Function            Color
'   Purpose             Determine the Background Color Of a Cell
'   @Param rng          Range to Determine Background Color of
'   @Param formatType   Default Value = 0
'                       0   Integer
'                       1   Hex
'                       2   RGB
'                       3   Excel Color Index
'   Usage               Color(A1)      -->   9507341
'                       Color(A1, 0)   -->   9507341
'                       Color(A1, 1)   -->   91120D
'                       Color(A1, 2)   -->   13, 18, 145
'                       Color(A1, 3)   -->   6
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function Color(rng As Range, Optional formatType As Integer = 0)     As Variant
    Dim colorVal As Variant
    colorVal = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    Select Case formatType
        Case 1
            Color = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(colorVal, 6)
        Case 2
            Color = (colorVal Mod 256) & ", " & ((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256) & ", " & (colorVal \ 65536)
        Case 3
            Color = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
        Case Else
            Color = colorVal
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: If RGB() numbers were encoded as `R*256^2 + G*256 + B` this wouldn't be VBA, where the simplest things must be quirky. In fact it's the other way around: `B*256^2 + G*256 + R`

Comment: @Nickolay Of course yes that is part of an endless pile of VBA quirks. I must have typed this too fast for my own good. Thanks for the catch!! Fixed. Kind of surprised it took this long for someone to point it out. And surprised I messed it up because I knew that quirk when I wrote this method and it shows in how I wrote out the R, G, B.

Comment: Yeah. I only noticed because I thought it would be faster to do the math by hand instead of copy-pasting your (correct) code and running it:)

Comment: @Nickolay FWIW the quirk is on the Excel object model (the type library), not VBA (the language). Excel v1.0 already needed back-compat with 1985 worksheets, and I'd assume Excel worksheet cell interior was a thing quite a few years before CSS was even a dream. Speaking of quirks...

Comment: @Mathieu: hey, thanks for your efforts on rubberduck, by the way!

Comment: @Nickolay on behalf of everyone in the dev team, thanks! star us on GitHub! =)

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually a quirk of VBA.  R would be the first, hence lowest (1st) byte. G would be the second, hence 2nd byte.  B would be the third, hence the 3rd byte.  If you would call it a quirk, it would be a quirk that dates back to the 70s.

Comment: @MarkWalsh I get your argument from a computing perspective but Excel's implementation is quirky because iirc every other website, programming language, and software I've ever used does it the other way. Excel says that _red_ is **#0000FF** and **255**. Google _"hex color red"_ and every link says **#FF0000**. I don't know if Excel preceded the standard. What I do know is that it is an outlier that requires me to break my instincts.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff interesting, I didn't even realize that.  I always used the documentation to compose my bytes, so never paid attention to ordering.

Answer (score 29):

good to see that Mr Wyatt uses the fast method of color to RGB

```
R = C Mod 256
G = C \ 256 Mod 256
B = C \ 65536 Mod 256
```

which is many times faster  than those using hex str with left mid right
that some recommend

Answer (score 8):

The other answer did not work for me. I found that:

```
R = C And 255
G = C \ 256 And 255
B = C \ 256 ^ 2 And 255
```

and it worked properly.

Comment: Yours and Harry's both work. F.i. Red value of `RGB(50,100,200) = RGB(50,100,200) Mod 256 ` and red value of `RGB(50,100,200) =  RGB(50,100,200)  And 255 `

Comment: I suspect it works because you are under a special case, where `X Mod 256` is the same as `X And 255`. By doing an `And 255` you are in effect filtering all bits from 256 onwards, and only keep the first 8 bits, which is exactly the size of 256. Same would work for 128, 64, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is another way to skin the cat

```
'
' Type definition in declarations
'
Type RGBcolor
    r As Long
    g As Long
    b As Long
End Type
'
' Inverse RGB function
'
Function GetRGB(ByVal x As Long) As RGBcolor
    With GetRGB
        .r = x Mod 256
        x = x \ 256
        .g = x Mod 256
        x = x \ 256
        .b = x Mod 256
    End With
End Function
'
'  Sub to test the GetRGB function
'
Sub test(x As Long)
Dim c As RGBcolor
c = GetRGB(x) ' returns RGB values: c.r, c.g, c.b
Debug.Print "Original", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Recombined value"
Debug.Print x, c.r, c.g, c.b, RGB(c.r, c.g, c.b)
End Sub
'
'
***** IMMEDIATE WINDOW *****
test 1000
Original      Red           Green         Blue          Recombined value
 1000          232           3             0             1000
```

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

Drop these 3 self-explanatory one-liner's into a module, then use them in VBA or worksheet formulas:

```
Function rr(rgbCode): rr = rgbCode Mod 256: End Function
Function g(rgbCode): g = (rgbCode \ 256) Mod 256: End Function
Function b(rgbCode): b = rgbCode \ 65536: End Function
```

<sub>(I couldn't use a single **`R`** for red's function name since it's [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885618/why-cant-a-single-letter-udf-name-use-c-or-r) for use in the *Goto* <kbd>F5</kbd> & *Name* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> dialogs.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Should note, for the hex values, if you're exporting out to HTML you're going to get quirks too.

Ideally you'd create the hex string from the individual colours, rather than returning a hex from the ColorVal number.

The reason being you can get some invalid hex numbers if the cell is a 'pure' colour like green/blue

RED - RGB(255,0,0) returns 'FF'  - it should return 'FF0000'

BLUE - RGB(0,0,255) returns 'FF00000'  - it should return '0000FF'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wShur.png)

If you used these to create HTML/CSS colour output, you'd get RED for any blue cells.

I modified the script to assemble each two character hex 'chunk' based on the RGB values, with a UDF that just pads with a leading 0 where output of one character is returned ( hopefully if you're reading this, you can make something similar )

```visualbasic
Color = ZeroPad(Hex((colorVal Mod 256)), 2) & ZeroPad(Hex(((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256)), 2) & ZeroPad(Hex((colorVal \ 65536)), 2)
```

--Edit : forgot to include the code for the UDF...

```
Function ZeroPad(text As String, Cnt As Integer) As String
'Text is the string to pad
'Cnt is the length to pad to, for example  ZeroPad(12,3) would return a string '012' , Zeropad(12,8) would return '00000012' etc..
Dim StrLen As Integer, StrtString As String, Padded As String, LP As Integer


StrLen = Len(Trim(text))


    If StrLen < Cnt Then

        For LP = 1 To Cnt - StrLen

            Padded = Padded & "0"

        Next LP

    End If

ZeroPad = Padded & Trim(text)

ENDOF:


End Function
```

BTW - If you want the hex codes as displayed in the form editor ( which inexplicably has it's own standard , apart from the normal HTML Hex Colours )

```
    Case 4  ' ::: VBA FORM HEX :::
    Color = "&H00" & ZeroPad(Hex((colorVal \ 65536)), 2) &  ZeroPad(Hex(((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256)), 2) & ZeroPad(Hex((colorVal Mod 256)), 2) & "&"
```

Comment: +1 I think you are fleshing out what is noted in the comments under my answer (that Excel has the hex parts in reverse order of HTML implementations). And then also adding leading zeros. The latter btw could be done without a new function. The worksheet function to convert to hex has a 2nd parameter for length. So: `WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(colorVal Mod 256, 2) & WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256, 2) & WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(colorVal \ 65536, 2)` for your first one and `WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(colorVal, 6)` for your second one.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Balhoff´s VBA script works fine. All credits go to him.

In case you´d like to get the color codes/indexes of conditionally formatted cells as well, the code may be amended like this:

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------
'   Function            Color
'   Purpose             Determine the Background Color Of a Cell
'   @Param rng          Range to Determine Background Color of
'   @Param formatType   Default Value = 0
'                       0   Integer             color of cell, not considering conditional formatting color
'                       1   Hex                 color of cell, not considering conditional formatting color
'                       2   RGB                 color of cell, not considering conditional formatting color
'                       3   Excel Color Index   color of cell, not considering conditional formatting color
'                       4   Integer             "real" visible color of cell (as the case may be the conditional formatting color)
'                       5   Hex                 "real" visible color of cell (as the case may be the conditional formatting color)
'                       6   RGB                 "real" visible color of cell (as the case may be the conditional formatting color)
'                       7   Excel Color Index   "real" visible color of cell (as the case may be the conditional formatting color)
'   Usage               Color(A1)      -->   9507341
'                       Color(A1, 0)   -->   9507341
'                       Color(A1, 1)   -->   91120D
'                       Color(A1, 2)   -->   13, 18, 145
'                       Color(A1, 3)   -->   6
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Function Color(rng As Range, Optional formatType As Integer = 0) As Variant
    Dim colorVal As Variant
    Select Case formatType
        Case 0 To 3
            colorVal = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Interior.Color
        Case 4 To 7
            colorVal = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    End Select
    Select Case formatType
        Case 0
            Color = colorVal
        Case 1
            Color = Hex(colorVal)
        Case 2
            Color = (colorVal Mod 256) & ", " & ((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256) & ", " & (colorVal \ 65536)
        Case 3
            Color = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Interior.ColorIndex
        Case 4
            Color = colorVal
        Case 5
            Color = Hex(colorVal)
        Case 6
            Color = (colorVal Mod 256) & ", " & ((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256) & ", " & (colorVal \ 65536)
        Case 7
            Color = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: A valuable addition sure and I appreciate the citation but a couple quick notes: **1)** DisplayFormat call will error if this is used as a Worksheet Function and **2)** Changing the second `Select Case formatType` to `Select Case formatType Mod 4` allows the deleting of cases 4 to 7 (unnecessary code duplication). I'd also probably choose to convert  the last `Case` in the big switch block to a `Case Else` to default on bad user input and convert the smaller switch block to `If formatType < 4 Then ... Else ... End If` but those last two are more personal choices.