# Range.Interior.Color Different Between Excel 2007 and Later

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm seeing that Range.Interior.Color returns different numbers for the same color in some cases, depending on whether it is running in Excel 2007, or Excel 2010 or 2013.

Is that expected?? I'm surprised.

Range.Interior.Color is the background color ("Fill Color") of the cell. In the Immediate pane, you can read it like this:

?ActiveCell.Interior.Color

And set it like this:

ActiveCell.Interior.Color = 10921638

Examples:

Example 1:

(these are the same color though their Range.Interior.Color are different.)

- Excel 2007:       10855845
- Excel 2010/2013:  10921638

Example 2:

- Excel 2007:       14922893
- Excel 2010/2013:  14857357

Example 3:

- Excel 2007:       14211288
- Excel 2010/2013:  14277081

Any suggestions? For now, I'm using conditional compliling to set constants for one number or the other depending on VBA constant VBA7, which returns True for Excel 2010 or later and False for Excel 2007 and earlier:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    'Excel 2010 or later:
    Const NO_SHADING_COLOR As Long = 16777215
    Const MAIN_HEADER_COLOR As Long = 10921638 'dark gray [in xl2007 s/b 10855845]
    Const SUB_HEADER_COLOR As Long = 14857357 'light blue [in xl2007 s/b 14922893]
    Const SUBSUB_HEADER_COLOR As Long = 14277081 'medium gray [in xl2007 s/b 14211288]
#Else
    'Excel 2007 or earlier:
    Const NO_SHADING_COLOR As Long = 16777215
    Const MAIN_HEADER_COLOR As Long = 10855845 'dark gray
    Const SUB_HEADER_COLOR As Long = 14922893 'light blue
    Const SUBSUB_HEADER_COLOR As Long = 14211288 'medium gray
#End If
```

UPDATE:

Yes, I understand that RGB can be used intead of Range.Interior.Color, and that RGB numbers can be extracted from Range.Interior.Color. But we can do that all day long and still get different sets of RGB numbers depending on Excel version, which effectively takes us back to the original problem.

For any given Range.Interior.Color number, yes it is equivalent to a certain set of RGB numbers. But the point is that depending on Excel version, in some cases you get different Range.Interior.Color numbers for the very same cell without changing the cell's color. If you extract that number to RGB numbers, then you just have different sets of RGB numbers depending on Excel version, which is no better than having the different Range.Interior.Color numbers depending on version.

These cell colors are being set by the user, using Excel's user interface for setting the cell's "Fill Color". The VBA code in this proejct does not set the colors. The VBA code only GETS the colors, and branches according to the color found in the cell being processed.

Aside from obvious exceptions like Application.Version, it isn't normal for object properties to randomly change like this from version to version. Consistency of object properties between versions is an important part of what allows VBA code to work across different versions. If it were not so, we'd have to conditional-compile virtually all our Excel VBA code.

Comment: Check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/24132665/2140173

Comment: Thanks, but that thread just shows how to extract RGB from Range.Interior.Color. That's interesting information but not to the point. The point is that I'm getting different numbers depending on Excel version. After converting to RGB, I've still got different numbers depending on Excel version.

Comment: I do not know if the OP is told if an answer is updated.  To be sure you know, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I haven't been able to reproduce this problem in a new workbook, so it may be workbook corruption. Normally Range.Interior.Color is reliable across versions, for all colors represented.

FWIW, this workbook was sent to me by another person, and that person is on Excel for Macintosh while I am on Windows, so creating the workbook on one platform and then using it on another may have been a factor in the corruption, if any (even though that should work fine).

Answer (score 2):

If you search for “Excel colour codes” you will find sites that list Excel’s 56 “official” colours.  You will not find any of numbers you list in the official list.

The Red, Green and Blue values for the numbers you list are:

```
             Red   Green   Blue 
10855845     165     165    165
10921638     166     166    166
 9868950     150     150    150  Grey 40%

14922893     141     180    227
14857357     141     180    226
16764057     153     204    255  Pale blue

14211288     216     216    216
14277081     217     217    217
12632256     192     192    192  Grey 25%
```

In each sub-table, the first two lines show your colour numbers.  Although the combined numbers like very different, you will notice the separate values are almost identical so the two alternative colours would look the same on the screen.  The third line shows the nearest official Excel colour and its name.

The question for you to investigate is: where have these non-standard colour numbers come from?  Are these colours being set by a program or has the palette been very subtly changed by a user?  I find it difficult to believe Microsoft released Excel 2007, 2010 and 2013 to you in this state.

**New section**

I have been playing with Excel colours and I am convinced your problem is related to the palette and the use of non-standard colours.

I do not have your range of versions so experimented with 2003 and 2007.

With 2003 there is a palette of 56 colours and a colour index with a value of 1 to 56.  I believe that Excel stores the colour index against a cell because:

- If with VBA you set a cell to an off-palette colour, Excel immediately changes it to an on-palette colour.
- If you change a colour on the palette, every use of that colour within the workbook immediately changes.

That is, with 2003 you can have any 56 colours but only 56 different colours.

Under 2003, I created a new workbook.  On the palette, I switched Red and Blue and I replaced Indigo, RGB(51, 51, 163), by RGB(167, 167, 167).  This is not a standard Excel colour but, if it was, it would be named something like Grey 30.  I coloured a few cells using these colours.

I opened this workbook with 2007 and saved it as an xlsm file.  The colours on the worksheet appeared unchanged.  I selected a new cell and defined a custom colour of RGB(167, 167, 167).  Visually the new cell was identical (to my eyes) to those coloured with the RGB(167, 167, 167) imported from 2003.  I then examined these cells via the palette and VBA:

```
Colour I    Appearance   Number according      Number according
had set     on screen    to palette            to VBA
255,0,0       Red        0,0,255 Blue          255,0,0
0,0,255       Blue       255,0,0 Red           0,0,255
167,167,167   Grey 30    51,51,153 Indigo      167,167,167      Imported from 2003
167,167,167   Grey 30    167,167,167 Grey 30   167,167,167      Created with 2007
```

The implication from the last line is that 2007 can handle custom colours correctly if defined within 2007 but gets hopelessly confused with imported custom colours.

My understanding is that 2007 to 2010 to 2013 involved incremental improvements but 2003 to 2007 was a total rewrite.  I would guess a bug in 2007 was fixed in 2010.

I believe the problem is the use of non-standard colours.  2007 may have a larger standard palette but RGB(167, 167, 167) is not on it.  I do not have 2010 or 2013 but suspect I would get different results if I tried this experiment with either of them.

I believe you must re-colour all cells that use these custom colours with standard colours.  You report two custom shades of grey and a custom variation of pale blue.  Surely 2007, 2010 and 2013 offer enough standard shades and colours?

Comment: The colors in the cells are set when the user picks a color from Excel's user interface for picking a "Fill Color" for a cell.

Comment: @GregLovern  The colour number for a cell can be set using VBA to anything the programmer wants or can be set by selecting a colour from the palette. The palette is under user control and can be changed.  I do not believe Microsoft has changed its standard colours since I have received workbooks created in different versions of Excel without encountering different colours.  If you do not want to blame your programmers, you need to ask which of your users is changing the palette.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that for any given color in the cell, Range.Interior.Color returns different numbers depending on the palette. In that case, RGB would also return different sets of numbers depending on palette, since any given Range.Interior.Color number always converts to the same set of RGB numbers. I'm surprised to hear that you get different numbers (whether Range.Interior.Color or RGB) depending on palette. Can you show an example of how Range.Interior.Color or RGB numbers can change just by changing the palette, without changing the cell's Fill Color?

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell the palette is a property of the workbook, not of the Excel Application. So when this workbook is opened by each version of Excel, it always has the same palette. The users are not changing the palette; I'm seeing this change in Range.Interior.Color just by opening the workbook in one verson of Excel, then closing the workbook without making any changes, and then opening it in another version of Excel. No changes to the workbook at all; just opening in different versions of Excel, and seeing different Range.Interior.Color numbers for the same, unchanged cell.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that for any given color in the cell, Range.Interior.Color returns different numbers depending on the palette. No.  Once the colour of a cell is set, changing the palette does not change the cell.

Comment: No changes to the workbook at all; just opening in different versions of Excel, and seeing different Range.Interior.Color numbers for the same, unchanged cell.  When I have had problems with colours in the past, the user has admitted playing with the palette.  I have no explanation for the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @GregLovern Just reread my last but one comment where I quote you and then reply.  My reply is wrong; don't know what I was thinking.  For 2003, changing the palette immediately changes all cells that reference it.  I have not experimented with later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some work with a project and come across something that may help with this whole question.  I have been working on Excel 2010 (and don't have access to any more versions at the moment), but found out that there is more than one way to refer to 3 x 8-bit colours.  While we are all familiar with RGB (Red-Green-Blue) references I came across someone using BGR (Blue-Green-Red) and got very confused in a similar manner to the original post.  I remember doing work a long time ago on XL2003 and found that the colours were "correct", so I suspect that MS have changed the references without telling everybody (their documentation states RGB).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the RGB() function instead of those numbers, as for example in

```
   Activecell.Interior.Color = RGB(200,150,230)
```

If you would like the constants, then

```
    Const RED = 200
    Const GRN = 150
    Const BLU = 230
    ......
    Activecell.Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GRN, BLU)
```

As for "Is it expected?", here is this: `Color = 10921638` is `RGB(165, 165, 165)` while `Color = 10855845` is `RGB(166, 166, 166)`. I have no access to Excel 2007 at the moment, but if your color values are indeed system's "dark grey" in both cases then Microsoft has a changed the value for "dark grey" between the Excel versions. I suspect you do not care or able to see the difference between the two anyway... You might consider using the same color in all versions, I think.

Comment: your *answer* is somehow an alternative solution but it **doesn't** answer the original question asked which was *Range.Interior.Color returns different numbers for the same color in some cases, depending on whether it is running in Excel 2007, or Excel 2010 or 2013*. **Is that expected??**

Comment: @vba4all     did I misread this: "Any suggestions? For now, I'm using conditional compliling..."

Comment: to me the question being asked here is rather straight forward, the numbers change in different XL versions, is that expected? why does it happen then?

Comment: Even though someone experienced in XL sees potential in your answer as it stands it is very poor IMHO. You should explain the difference in comparison to the OP's current approach and why your alternative is better. The part about constants seems a bit irrelevant to the actual problem.

Comment: @vba4all You are free to edit the answer, I do not mind a bit. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to give you tips on how to give a good answer. If I wanted to answer myself, I would. Since I have been here quite a bit longer then you and answered a lot more questions than you at the moment I am happy to help new users - both askers and answerers improve the quality of their online contributions.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm actually intersted in both questons:  is the behavior expected, and any suggestions on a better workaround than conditional compile. Gene, thanks for the suggestion; I'd looked at RGB. But conditional compile as I'm doing now seems a bit easier than having three constants per color.

Comment: @GregLovern conditional compiling may not be necessary if you understand what the .Interior.Color returns and how it's calculated. It would help if someone shared why the number is different and if there is an easier way to calculate it.

Comment: @Greg Lovern 4 colors * 3 color components = 12 lines of code. You have 13 lines of code :)

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky adding a reference link (and maybe a quote) to the document saying "Yes, this indeed is expected it changed between versions." would gain an upvote from me. *hint hint wink wink*

Comment: @RubberDuck But some of the Range.Interior.Color numbers are the same between all of these versions. It isn't normal for all properties to return different values between versions; if they did, we'd have to conditional-compile virtually all our code.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky Not true about your solution requiring only 12 lines of code; it would require much more. There are many places in the code where I branch based on that color; currently I just check the constant and branch accordingly. With RGB instead of conditional compile, I'd either have to add variables for each color and assign them according to Excel version, or test for all three R/G/B each time and branch according to all three, a fairly complex test which should probably go in a new function. If you believe it can be done with only your 12 lines, I'd like to see it.