# Set RGB() using VBA in excel 2013, open this file with excel 2007, the cell background color is different with i set

Tags: excel, vba

I set the background color of some cells with `RGB(198, 224, 180)` in excel 2013, and then in VBA to check it:

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(I, J).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180) Then
     ActiveSheet.Cells(I, J).Locked = False
End If
```

It works fine.

But when i open this file with excel 2007, check this background color of these cells, it is `RGB(197, 224, 178)`, led the VBA cannot work.

I cannot find the difference between different excel version in google, who knows why to help me?

Comment: Is `RGB(198, 224, 180)` a theme color by any chance? Themes can vary between versions...

Comment: have you checked [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071931/range-interior-color-different-between-excel-2007-and-later)? While [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa) tells that colors are saved as 32bit and have full access to 24bit, there are lots of ppl telling that this is not the case. Some ppl told me that colors are just saved 16bit (while they can be set in 24bit) but i couldn't find any proof for this (so you better ignore this) ^o^;

Comment: not theme color, the "Fill Color" button, it should be the background color of cells.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ColorIndex property to replace RGB() function, sure, the background color is changed to the standard color, cannot customized. Then the script works fine.
Just implement my requirement, but i am still understand difference between different excel version.