# Make bar graphs different colors

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code to change the colors of my bars in my bar graph but now it gives me a type mismatch. Please help me fix my code.

```
Sub UpdateChart()

Dim myChartObj As ChartObject
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim mySeries(1 To 10) As Series
Dim myChartFormat(1 To 10) As ChartFormat
Dim myFillFormat(1 To 10) As FillFormat
Dim myColorFormat(1 To 10) As ColorFormat

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate

Set myChart = ActiveChart

For i = 1 To 10

    Set mySeries(i) = myChart.SeriesCollection(i)
    Set myChartFormat(i) = mySeries(i).Format
    Set myFillFormat(i) = myChartFormat(i).Fill
    Set myColorFormat(i) = myFillFormat(i).ForeColor


     If i = 1 Then

    myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 7))

    ElseIf i = 2 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 7))

    ElseIf i = 3 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 8))

    ElseIf i = 4 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 9))

    ElseIf i = 5 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 10))

    ElseIf i = 6 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 11))

    ElseIf i = 7 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 12))

    ElseIf i = 8 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 13))

    ElseIf i = 9 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 14))

    ElseIf i = 10 Then

     myColorFormat(i).RGB = getRGB1(Cells(12, 15))

     End If




Next i



End Sub

Function getRGB1(rcell) As String
    Dim sColor As String

    sColor = Right("000000" & Hex(rcell.Interior.Color), 6)
    getRGB1 = Right(sColor, 2) & Mid(sColor, 3, 2) & Left(sColor, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Type mismatch *where* ?

Comment: You are getting that `type mismatch` error because `getRGB1` is returning a string like `FFFFFF` whereas `.RGB` is expecting something like `RGB(0, 128, 0)`

Comment: Please see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property) on how to retrieve those values.

Comment: I am now trying it with a value like RGB(0, 128,0) and it is giving me a 400 error the second time I run the line Set mySeries(i) = myChart.SeriesCollection(i)

Comment: That could be probably because you do not have that series collection.

Comment: hmm yes
So I added this function and the second to last line is highlighted in red?
Why

Function getRGB2(rcell) As String
    Dim C As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim G As Long
    Dim B As Long

    C = rcell.Interior.Color
    R = C Mod 256
    G = C \ 256 Mod 256
    B = C \ 65536 Mod 256
    getRGB2 = "RBG(" & R & "," & G & "," & B ")"
End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the color of each cell in range G12:R12

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim myChart As Chart

    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    For i = 1 To 10
        With myChart.SeriesCollection(1)
            .Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Cells(12, i + 6).Interior.Color
        End With
    End Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: YEEEEESSSS GOD BLESS YOUR SOUL