# Plot excel chart from Matlab, how to change colors?

Tags: excel, matlab

Hi I try to change the color of my excel bar chart via MATLAB.

```
wksheet     = eWorkbook.Worksheets.Item('Sheet2');
co          = wksheet.ChartObjects.Item(1); % select the plot (this selects the first plot)
nbSeries    = co.Chart.SeriesCollection.count;
% Delete previous series
for i= 1:nbSeries
    Series = invoke(co.Chart,'SeriesCollection',1);
    invoke(Series,'Delete');
end
% Create Series
nbNewSeries = size(organizedData.Page2.CorrToIndex2Txlsx,1);
for ii = 1:nbNewSeries
    NewSeries = invoke(co.Chart.SeriesCollection,'NewSeries');
    NewSeries.XValues   = organizedData.Page2.CorrToIndex2Txlsx(ii,2);
    NewSeries.Values    = organizedData.Page2.CorrToIndex2Txlsx(ii,3);
    NewSeries.Name      = organizedData.Page2.CorrToIndex2Txlsx{ii,1};
end
```

I have tried this:

```
NewSeries3.MarkerBackgroundColor = paletteColors(iii,:)*255;
```

but I get an error:

```
Parameter must be scalar.
```

Do you know how can I change colors from MATLAB?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Where did `paletteColors` and `iii` come from?

Comment: Try passing it a scalar as requested? I would use a decimal representation of the RGB triple as a single HEX value. So something like `NewSeries3.MarkerBackgroundColor = paletteColors(iii,1)*255^2 + paletteColors(iii,2)*255 + paletteColors(iii,3)` note Excel sometimes likes to represent colours as BGR instead of RGB so you might need to swap your 1st and 3rd colours

Comment: I apologize, paletteColors is a matrix with RGB value, iii is just an integer. So, I could write instead: NewSeries3.MarkerBackgroundColor = [180 125 160] for example;

Comment: If you look at the VBA documentation for [`MarkerBackgroundColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175712%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and the related [`RGB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc1dyw8b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you'll note that colors in Excel are represented as integers, not RGB vectors. Answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property) may be useful for calculating this integer from the RGB values.

Comment: @Wismerhill yes I understand that, my code converts your *1*-by-*3* matrix (i.e. `paletteColors(iii,:)`) to a scalar value in a way I would guess Excel wants it. Try it. Think of it like this, if your colour was `[0,0,255]` then that's the same as a hex colour `#0000FF` which is the decimal number `255`. If you colour was `[0,255,0]` then your hex colour is `#00FF00` which converting to decimal is `15*16^2 + 15*16^3` which is `(15*16+15)*16^2` = `(255)*256`

Comment: Hi Dan, Thank you very much for your explanation. your post solves my problem.