# How to check the background color of an excel cell

Tags: vb.net, excel

In my program, I set the background color of an excel cell using:

```
sheet.cells(row, column).interior.color = System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

In another part of my program, I want to see if the color is red, but this code:

```
If(sheet.cells(row, column).interior.color = System.Drawing.Color.Red) Then
    'Do something
End If
```

It returns an 'Type cast invalid' exception.

If the color is checked by:

```
If(sheet.cells(row, column).style.interior.color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red))
    'Do something
End If
```

The colors are said to be not equal (even though the cell is red), because the interior color is 16777215 and the color translator returns 255.

How can I compare the color the right way?

Comment: Is this in VB.NET as you've tagged, or VBA?

Comment: See if this link helps you in converting the color to you RGB format to compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property

Comment: vb.net, it's a plugin written in visual studio, using the microsoft interrop library

Comment: Okay, it's solved. By using the cells(x, y).style.Interior.color, I was checking for the interior color of the style, not of the cell itself. Please let me know if I need to delete this question, as it was a dumb one...

Comment: Use the XLRgbColor enumeration instead of System.Drawing.Color https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241561

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that sure, but System.Drawing.Color.xxx is not existing in vba. You could try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

If (ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)) Then
    'Do something
End If
```

You could also have a look to `.Interior.ColorIndex`
I think you should change the tag of question to vba instead vb.net.

Best regards.

Comment: Tried this, does not work. There are no exceptions, but the colors are said to be different. That said, this is a vb.net plugin, not excel-vba, so that could make a difference.