# Obtain cell fill color and delete cell values based on that color

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am new completely new to coding in excel (2013) VB and I need to write some code to do the following:

I have a 2013 workbook with multiple tabs.  I need to delete values (could be hard coded numbers, categorical data [e.g., "Yes/No"], or formulas) from only SOME of these tabs (let's say tabs X and Y) **based upon cell fill color**.

1) First, how do I obtain the color index or, more specifically the color index property (I might not be using the exact correct terminology here)?  I assume I need to get this exact number from a function and then plug this number into some sub to delete the conditioned values.

2) Then, how do I use that value to write a sub (?) that will delete all the values in that specific cell color for tabs X an Y?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are you coding in VB or VBA?  They're kind of similar but an important distinction...If it's VBA, you can start recording macros and get a pretty good chunk of what you need to do, although it *will* need to be cleaned up a bit (but you'll learn A LOT about the Excel object model).

Comment: For started you should have read [Ask] and taken the [tour], then you need to be clearer about the actual tool.  VB.NET can work with excel, but it sounds like you are using vba/excel-vba which is entirely different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cell's color property is held in the cell's `interior` object. To get the color from cell `B3` in Tab 'X' you could do:

```
 Dim cellColor as Long
 cellColor = Sheets("X").Range("B3").Interior.Color
```

Now the cell's color is held in variable `cellColor`.

This color property is a little oddball though. It's a numeric representation of the RGB, taking the form: `(R*256^2 + G*256 + B)` Kind of like a bitmask, but at the byte level. [Check out the function in the second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property) for a great way to get at these values if you need them.

Really your best bet is to paint a cell, then run a macro to tell you what the color code is.

Pretending like you want to delete everything in Sheet `X` Range `A1:Z5000` that are colored red (65535),  you could do something like:

```
 Dim checkCell as Range 'cells are range objects


 For each checkCell in Sheet("X").Range("A1:Z5000").Cells 'loop through all the cells assigning the cell in each iteration to variable checkCell
      If checkCell.Interior.Color = 65535 Then 'is it red?
          checkCell.ClearContents 'null out the value
      End If
 Next checkCell
```

Comment: Or `Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` for conditional formatting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx

Comment: I apologize if I did not use correct terminology.  I am completely new to this line of work and was given a task with a tight deadline and so I reached out to the community because I didn't have a ton of time to research.  Your comments were very helpful.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Your question and terminology seemed fine to me. The question was just a bit broad, so I attempted answer it broadly. I think this will get you in the ballpark, or at least close enough to do some damage.