# Why can't a single-letter UDF name use C or R?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions, excel-r1c1-notation, vba

I can write the following valid VBA functions:

```
Public Function C() As Long
  C = 5
End Function

Public Function R() As Long
  R = 6
End Function
```

But I can't use them in an Excel formula, without qualifying them with the VBA project or module name.

FWIW, `Function N` and `Function T` are valid too, but they clash with built-in functions.

I *think* `C` and `R` must be reserved names in Excel formulas, but I don't understand why. Any use of `C`/`R` as function calls would be parseable as function calls because they would be immediately followed by a `(`, whereas any use of `C`/`R` as R1C1 notation would *not* be immediately followed by a `(`.

Interstingly, I can call the functions if I qualify the function call with the name of the project and/or module:

```
=VBAProject.C()
5

=Module1.C()
5

=VBAProject.Module1.C()
5
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64):

> Tip: You cannot use the uppercase and lowercase characters "C", "c",
>   "R", or "r" as a defined name, because they are all used as a
>   shorthand for selecting a row or column for the currently selected
>   cell when you enter them in a Name or Go To text box.

I was aware of this limitation in defining named ranges. Evidently it extends to naming UDFs as well (which makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows 1252 codepage, there are several characters that can't be used as the first/only character in a formula call to User Defined Function, but those UDFs can be called when prefixed with the project name or module name, or both:

```
'Without Project/Module prefix, these characters are 
'reserved for Column/Row shorthand
=VBAProject.C()
=VBAProject.N()

'Without Project/Module prefix, these characters are 
'reserved for built-in function names
=VBAProject.R()
=VBAProject.T()

'Without Project/Module prefix, these characters are 
'special characters
=VBAProject.€()
=VBAProject.ˆ()
=VBAProject.˜()
=VBAProject.Ñ()
```

Interestingly, if the function `Ñ()` takes an argument, and the Project/Module name is omitted, then Excel auto-converts the formula to `N(arg)`, which is a completely different function, and `Ñ(arg)` will not be called.