# Color values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've done a bit of searching for this one and cannot find the answer (or maybe looking in the wrong places :/)

I am trying to find a reference for the colour values used in excel VBA. I have a few simple lines of code which change the background colour in a selected cell (in this case I am using a simple macro to invoke the code).

I have a come across this value which was generated by the macro recorder:

```
Selection.Interior.Color = 15773696
```

My preference is to use RGB (the RGB equivalent of the above example is 128, 128, 128) and I have been trying find out where the macro recorder got this value from.

Apologies if this is a FAQ.

TIA

Comment: You say _the RGB equivalent of the above example is 128, 128, 128)_ well, sorry, no it's not.  RGB of `15773696` is `0` `176` `240`

Answer (score 1):

To convert the output in the terms of RGB:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertColor()

    Convert2RGB 15773696

End Sub

Public Sub Convert2RGB(ByVal clr As Long)

    Dim R As Long, G As Long, B As Long

    R = clr Mod 256
    G = clr \ 256 Mod 256
    B = clr \ 65536 Mod 256

    'Or
    'R = clr And 255
    'G = clr \ 256 And 255
    'B = clr \ 256 ^ 2 And 255

    Debug.Print "R:" & R & " G:" & G & " B:" & B    '15773696 -> R:0 G:176 B:240

    Debug.Print RGB(R, G, B)                        'R:0 G:176 B:240 -> 15773696

End Sub
```

---

From SO: [Return RGB values from Range.Interior.Color (or any other Color Property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property)

> *...The number is a mathematical combination of the RGB values (B*256^2 +
> G*256 + R) and a conversion of the hex color value to a decimal number
> (base 16 to base 10)...*

> *...a decimal conversion of the typical hexidecimal numbers that we are
> used to seeing for colors in html e.g. "66FF66"...*

---

More details (external link): [Determining the RGB Value of a Color](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010180_Determining_the_RGB_Value_of_a_Color.html)

Comment: Thanks for taking to time to answer. Appreciated :)