# Set chart series color by cells interior

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I wonder how I can change each point color on a series by the interior of the cell it refers. I'm almost there...

First, it's a 11-dimension series and I created an array to store the colors:

```
Dim VectorC(0 To 10) As Long
For x = 0 To 10:
    VectorC(x) = SH1.Cells(12 + x, 3).Interior.Color
Next x
```

So far, so good. However, when I try so set the color series `CH0101`:

```
CH0101.Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.Color = VectorC(0)
```

I get an error (because `Color` is missing on `CH0101.Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor` class).

I know how to change the series color with a `RGB` attribute but, to do that, I have to store the colors with a `RGB array` and I know I can't do that.

Any ideas?? Thanks.

Comment: Convert the color to RGB? Something like the function here: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010180_Determining_the_RGB_Value_of_a_Color.html Or this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property

Comment: @BigBen Got it! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to add a working model to this ? as I enjoyed playing with it.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rngOfColors As Range
        Set rngOfColors = ws.Range("A5:A9")

    Dim col As Collection
        Set col = New Collection

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each cell In rngOfColors
        col.Add cell.Interior.Color, CStr(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell

    Dim chartObject As chartObject
        Set chartObject = ws.ChartObjects(1)

    Dim myChart As chart
        Set myChart = chartObject.chart

    Dim mySeriesCol As SeriesCollection
        Set mySeriesCol = myChart.SeriesCollection

    Dim mySeries As Series

    i = 0
    For Each mySeries In mySeriesCol
       Dim myPoint As point
        For Each myPoint In mySeries.Points
            myPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = col(CStr(i))
        Next myPoint
            i = i + 1
    Next mySeries
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BigBen I updated the code with the following:

```
Dim VectorC(0 To 10, 1 To 3) As Long
For x = 0 To 10:
    VectorC(x, 1) = SH1.Cells(12 + x, 2).Interior.Color Mod 256
    VectorC(x, 2) = (SH1.Cells(12 + x, 2).Interior.Color \ 256) Mod 256
    VectorC(x, 3) = SH1.Cells(12 + x, 2).Interior.Color \ 65536
Next x

CH0101.Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(VectorC(0, 1), VectorC(0, 2), VectorC(0, 3))
CH0101.Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(VectorC(1, 1), VectorC(1, 2), VectorC(1, 3))...
```

And it worked! Learned something today... :)