# I need to extract revisions from different sheets within various workbooks. Each document has a different number of revisions, how would I do that?

Tags: excel, vba

I thought I should reword my question. Here is what I am trying to do and what I have done so far:
Steps:

1. Open Selected Files (DONE)
2. Obtain File number. (DONE)
3. Obtain File revision. (DONE)
4. Look for cells where the entry starts with 27 and usually has letters after, so like 27A, 27B, 27C.....27AB,27AC,27AD,...27XXX. (Problem is the cell contains something like "27AB. Some sentences etc."
5. Copy cells that have 27 in them (As mentioned above) but just the first 'word' like just the 27A, or 27AB etc.
6. When the last 27XXX is reached, stop doing it.

The last three parts are where I am stuck.

```
'SELECT REQUIRED WORKBOOKS

Dim fileNames As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'does not show the windows opening
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Range("A2").Select
fileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Open File(s)", 
MultiSelect:=True)

'OBTAIN Number AND REV FROM COVER PAGE OF Document

For i = 1 To UBound(fileNames)
Workbooks.Open fileNames(i)
Sheets(1).Select
Range("E4", "F4").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("MainFile.xlsm").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
Workbooks.Open fileNames(i)
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This sounds like a complex problem - perhaps too complex for a single question, and as a result there is no single correct answer. The usual etiquette is to break the problem down, and provide information on where you are having problems. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim i As Long, a As Long, fileNames As Variant, ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range, addr As String
    ReDim arr(0) As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    fileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xlsx,*.xlsx", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

    For i = LBound(fileNames) To UBound(fileNames)

        '1. Open Selected Files (DONE)
        With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fileNames(i), ReadOnly:=True)
            With .Worksheets("sheet1")

                '2. Obtain File number. (DONE) / 3. Obtain File revision. (DONE)
                .Cells(4, "E").Copy _
                  Destination:=ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

                '4. Look for cells where the entry starts with 27 and usually has letters after ...
                Set r = .Cells.Find(What:="27*", After:=.Cells(1), _
                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not r Is Nothing Then
                    addr = r.Address(0, 0)
                    Do
                        '5a. Copy cells that have 27 in them (As mentioned above) but just the first 'word' like just the 27A, or 27AB etc.
                        ReDim Preserve arr(a)
                        arr(a) = Split(r.Value2 & Space(1), Space(1))(0)
                        Set r = .Cells.FindNext(After:=r)
                    While addr <> r.Address(0, 0)
                End If

                '5b. Copy cells that have 27 in them (As mentioned above) but just the first 'word' like just the 27A, or 27AB etc.
                ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) = _
                  Application.Transpose(arr)

            End With
            '6. When the last 27XXX is reached, stop doing it.
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With

    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific regarding the details!
The code below is on the basis that the "27xyz" is in column A.
Where do you want to copy the "27..." values to? Another worksheet in the individual workbooks? Or one destination workbook?

Code updated based on comment "Here is the sample file. TheAviationist"
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_o_bJAYLT3wQ5v8Ij0_PFQALI6v-wCVM/view?usp=sharing)

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoItAll()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Call Create_a_WorkbookCopy
    Call CreateSheetStrings27
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Strings_27" Then
            ws.Select
            Call FilterCells
            Call CopyFilteredRows2otherWorksheet
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    Next ws
    Call SplitText
    '   Call DeleteAllDataSheets
    '     or
    '   Call CopyStrings27toNewWorkbook
End Sub

Sub DeleteAllDataSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Strings_27" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            'Debug.Print ws.Name
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub CopyStrings27toNewWorkbook()
    Sheets("Strings_27").Copy
End Sub

Sub CreateSheetStrings27()
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Strings_27").Select
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Strings_27" Then
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Name = "Strings_27"
    Sheets("Strings_27").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub Create_a_WorkbookCopy()
Dim newFileName As String
    'create a copy of the original workbook

    If Not ThisWorkbook.Name Like "*_COPY*" Then
        newFileName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "_COPY.xls")
        newFileName = Split(newFileName, ".")(0)
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs newFileName, xlExcel12
    End If
End Sub

Sub FilterCells() 'This only works if there are now empty rows'
    Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="27*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub

Sub RemoveFilter() 'This only works if there are now empty rows'
    'Range("A:A").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub



Sub FilterCellsWithEmptyRows()
Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Range("A1:" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="27*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub

Sub CopyFilteredRows2otherWorksheet()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
MsgBox "There are no filtered rows"
Exit Sub
End If
Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
rng.UnMerge
lastRow = Sheets("Strings_27").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
If lastRow = 1 Then lastRow = -1

'Copy the sheet name
Sheets("Strings_27").Range("A1").Offset(lastRow + 1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets("Strings_27").Range("A1").Offset(lastRow + 1, 0).Font.Bold = True
Sheets("Strings_27").Range("A1").Offset(lastRow + 1, 0).Font.Size = 20
'Copy the filtered values only
rng.Copy Sheets("Strings_27").Range("A1").Offset(lastRow + 2, 0)
Sheets("Strings_27").Range("A:A").WrapText = False
End Sub

Sub CopyFilteredRows2otherWorkbook()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
If Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False Then
MsgBox "There are no filtered rows"
Exit Sub
End If

'The file "DestinationWorkbook.xls" must be open!
Set wb = Workbooks("DestinationWorkbook.xls")
Set rng = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.Name = "Strings_27"
rng.Copy Range("A1")
End Sub

Sub SplitText()
Dim SplitRange As Range
Dim myRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Sheets("Strings_27").Select
Set SplitRange = Range("A:A") '.CurrentRegion
SplitRange.TextToColumns Destination:=SplitRange.Offset(, 1), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
Range("C:ZZ").ClearContents
Range("B1").Value = "1st word"
Range("B1").Font.Bold = True
Range("B1").Font.Size = 20
Range("B1").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Columns("B:B").Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

'Format Column B = Result Column
lastRow = Sheets("Strings_27").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set myRange = Columns("A:A")
myRange.Copy
Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("B1").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Set myRange = Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
myRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 204)
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("B:B").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("C1").Select
End Sub

Sub TestColor()
    Debug.Print getRGB2(Range("B2"))
End Sub

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property
'= https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010180_Determining_the_RGB_Value_of_a_Color.html
Function getRGB2(rcell) As String
    Dim C As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim G As Long
    Dim B As Long

    C = rcell.Interior.Color
    R = C Mod 256
    G = C \ 256 Mod 256
    B = C \ 65536 Mod 256
    getRGB2 = "R=" & R & ", G=" & G & ", B=" & B & "   =RGB(" & R & ", " & G & ", " & B & ")"
End Function


Sub SplitText()
Dim SplitRange As Range
Set SplitRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
SplitRange.TextToColumns Destination:=SplitRange.Offset(, 1), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
Range("C:Z").ClearContents
Range("B1").Value = "1st word"
End Sub
```

.
.
.
**Result Screenshot**

[image: result_data_screenshot]

.
.
.
**Create sample data**
To create sample data from the worksheet copy this formula B1 or C1 and copy it down several rows:
="=Range("""&CELL("address",A1)&""")="""&A1&""""

[image]

Comment: Each 27XXX entry is in the column A but there is a space of 11 rows between each successive "27" block. I want VBA to read the files and to put them in a sheet to look something like this:

Doc. Number: ####
REV: XX
Blocks: 27A,27B,27C....27AB etc. until last available one in the respective document.

Also, in your code you have "27*" What does the star mean?

And I want it in a separate workbook. (Sorry I am new here)

Comment: You want to create one sheet with all the blocks from the different workbooks?

Comment: If there are empty lines in your worksheets you need to change 'FilterCells': see "Sub FilterCellsWithEmptyRows" above

Comment: Yeah, I want to create one sheet with all the blocks from the different workbooks.

Comment: Criteria1:="27*" does filter all text beginning with 27!

Comment: I edited my code that I posted to show my latest version, it successfuly extracts the number of the document and the revision. I just need to figure out the blocks now that I was talking about. Could you help integrate your code with mine please?

Comment: Could you please paste some rows of sample data? (e.g. a dropbox file, a google drive file or via a vba script: see **"create sample data"** formula above)

Comment: Yeah, I will send a document soon which outlines the layout of the sheets i am trying to work with.

Comment: Here is the sample file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_o_bJAYLT3wQ5v8Ij0_PFQALI6v-wCVM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have 200 similar files. If you look at the 27XX boxes, each of the 200 files has a different amount of them, they all start at A and go to their last entry, if they reach Z, it becomes AA,AB,AC etc as shown. My code extracts the document number as well as the revision from all 200 (takes ages but it works).

My issue is extracting the 27XX blocks because each file has a different amont of them, and Idk what algorithm to follow..hope that helps

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your sample document. Not sure if there is another issue regarding your "200 similar files" comment! ;-)

Comment: I am having an issue making it work, it gives an error at SplitText saying too Ambiguous. What I am doing is just opening a new file and going to developer and pasting the code and clicking play. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, Thanks! but now I have a new question hahah. (I like your little prank too, Actually saw it in the code but acted like I didn't) 

Is it possible to do it so that the output is in a separate Wokrbook?

Comment: Prank removed ;-) As we are working already on a workbook copy it might be sufficient to delete all data worksheets? (see Sub DeleteAllDataSheets) Also the alternative (Sub CopyStrings27toNewWorkbook) is just one line of code.

Comment: Ohh, so with this code I have to open each document right? and then I can run it? I can't have it open each document on its own like I did for the doc. number and rev?

Comment: Sorry! Read your question and your comment twice but still don't get what we are talking about now: 1 done, 2 done, 3 done, 4 solved, 5 solved, 6 solved ???

Comment: You might start a new question! Do you have a list of files? Are the files in one folder? What do you want? What have you tried already? You might create a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example** https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, I have a list of files. All excel files are in one folder. Using like 5 copies of the file I sent, I used the code I uploaded above to extract Doc. Number and Revision. Your code works in order to extract the blocks (27 stuff) but I was wondering if it is possible to make it do everything on its own, except select the files to go through.