# Set shape color to cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create RAG rated 'traffic lights' on an Excel dashboard. I have a conditionally formatted cell in the background which is set on a 3-color scale from green to red. I would like the 'traffic light' shapes on my dashboard to change color as that cell changes color.

So far, I have this code:

```
Sub ChangeTrafficLights()

Dim light As Shape
Dim colour As Range

   Set light = Worksheets(3).Shapes.Range(Array("Light1"))
   Set colour = Worksheets(2).Range("D95")

   light.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = colour.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

End Sub
```

Which comes up with a Type Mismatch error on line 4.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is it possible to link the colors?

Comment: Try this instead: `Dim light As Object`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `light` variable as an `object` rather than `Shape`

I.e. your code will be:

```
Dim light As Object
Dim colour As Range
...
```

This then allows you to set the variable to the shape array/range. For more info, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.range

Answer (score 0):

Set your shape object like so:

```
Set light = thisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Shapes("The Name of your Shape")
```

Now, the property `.Interior.Color` , does not return a value in RGB format. To set the shape's `.RGB` property, you need a color in RGB format eg. `(255,255,255)`.

So, what you need is to get `D95` cell's color in RGB format. Unfortunately as far as I know, this is not readily available.

However you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property) and [here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010180_Determining_the_RGB_Value_of_a_Color.html).

When you get the 3 values you need, you can then set the shape's color like so:

```
light.Fill.ForeColor.RGB =RGB(R,G,B)
```

**TL;DR**

```
Sub trafficLight()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim colour As Range
Dim light As Shape
Dim C As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim G As Long
Dim B As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The Name of your Worksheet")
Set colour = sht.Range("D95")
Set light = sht.Shapes("The name of your shape")

'''''''''''''Credits to Mr. Allen Wyatt''''''''''''''''''
C = colour.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color                 '
R = C Mod 256                                           '
G = C \ 256 Mod 256                                     '
B = C \ 65536 Mod 256                                   '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

light.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(R, G, B)

End Sub
```

Below an output sample, where the color of the shape follows the first cell's color.

[image]