# Grouping hex color values

Tags: matlab, colors, hex

I am trying to write my own 3d topography-type program in matlab that will take a 2d thermal image and create a 3d model based on the intensity of colors in the 2d image.(white is the highest peak, red is lower, orange is lower...) I have extrapolated the hex and RGB color values of each of the pixels and sorted them into an array that indexes the place of the pixel in the image. There are thousands of unique colors. I need to design an algorithm that will evaluate which color grouping each pixel falls into. (white, red, orange...) without having to physically view each unique color.

I have extracted the hex values from matlab into excel. I alpa-numerically ordered the values and saw that some adjacent values do not lie in the same color family. (ex. #00024C is blue and #000300 is black, yet they are adjacent) Is there some kind of threshold built into matlab that I can use to sort the colors?

Comment: Those colour values are in fact three values, one for each channel. i.e. `#00024C` is actually `00 red`, `02 green` and `4C blue`. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property) may be useful

Comment: There are several thiungs to consider: first, the application that generates the images colors the images by using a relation `intensity<->color`. This is commonly called a colormap, and if you know this relation, it is possible to convert it back. However, only if the format of the image does not change the data, as for example `jpeg` does to shrink the image file size. Therefore, it would be very helpful if you could provide an example image and the colormap. A commonly used colormap is [`hot`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hot.html), but in `hot`, orange is higher than red