# Change Cell color when it selected and back original color after leaving it

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to change Color Cell when I select it. I use this function but I can't back the original color of the Cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static rngcolor As Range
    If Not rngcolor Is Nothing Then rngcolor.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Set rngcolor = Target
    rngcolor.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Comment: You say _but I can't back the original color of the Cell._  This code sets the cell you leave to color Index xlNone.  Do you mean you want to put back whatever color was there before you selected it?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. May be the function is incorrect at all. The clue is to save the original color of the Cell in my worksheet where many different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the original Color as well as the cell reference.  Also, the user might select more than one cell, each of which may have its own color.

Here's a starting point to deal with these complexities.  Note that this accounts for the user selecting a contiguous range of >= 1 cells.  They may also select a non-contiguous mutli cell range.  A second more complex version provides for this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static rngcolor As Range
    Static OldColor As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long

    If Not rngcolor Is Nothing Then
        If IsArray(OldColor) Then
            On Error GoTo NoRestore
            For rw = 1 To rngcolor.Rows.Count
                For cl = 1 To rngcolor.Columns.Count
                    If IsEmpty(OldColor(rw, cl)) Then
                        rngcolor.Cells(rw, cl).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                    Else
                        rngcolor.Cells(rw, cl).Interior.Color = OldColor(rw, cl)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            If IsEmpty(OldColor) Then
                rngcolor.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Else
                rngcolor.Interior.Color = OldColor
            End If
        End If
    End If
NoRestore:
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set rngcolor = Target
    ReDim OldColor(1 To Target.Rows.Count, 1 To Target.Columns.Count)
    For rw = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
        For cl = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
            If Target.Cells(rw, cl).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                OldColor(rw, cl) = Empty
            Else
                OldColor(rw, cl) = Target.Cells(rw, cl).Interior.Color
            End If
        Next
    Next
    rngcolor.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Version to account for a non-contiguous range selection

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static rngcolor As Range
    Static OldColor As Variant
    Dim OldColrRng As Variant
    Dim ar As Long, rw As Long, cl As Long

    If Not rngcolor Is Nothing Then
        If IsArray(OldColor) Then
            On Error GoTo NoRestore
            For ar = 1 To rngcolor.Areas.Count
                For rw = 1 To rngcolor.Areas(ar).Rows.Count
                    For cl = 1 To rngcolor.Areas(ar).Columns.Count
                        If IsEmpty(OldColor(ar)(rw, cl)) Then
                            rngcolor.Areas(ar).Cells(rw, cl).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                        Else
                            rngcolor.Areas(ar).Cells(rw, cl).Interior.Color = OldColor(ar)(rw, cl)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            If IsEmpty(OldColor) Then
                rngcolor.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Else
                rngcolor.Interior.Color = OldColor
            End If
        End If
    End If
NoRestore:
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set rngcolor = Target
    ReDim OldColor(1 To Target.Areas.Count)
    For ar = 1 To Target.Areas.Count
        ReDim OldColrRng(1 To Target.Areas(ar).Rows.Count, 1 To Target.Areas(ar).Columns.Count)
        OldColor(ar) = OldColrRng
    Next
    For ar = 1 To Target.Areas.Count
        For rw = 1 To Target.Areas(ar).Rows.Count
            For cl = 1 To Target.Areas(ar).Columns.Count
                If Target.Areas(ar).Cells(rw, cl).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                    OldColor(ar)(rw, cl) = Empty
                Else
                    OldColor(ar)(rw, cl) = Target.Areas(ar).Cells(rw, cl).Interior.Color
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    rngcolor.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Note:  Using Static (or global) variables is vulnerable to being stopped by an error, either in this code or other code.  Depending on how important it is to restore the colors, you may want to store the Range reference and colors somewhere else: eg in cells on a (hidden) sheet, in (hidden) names, in a external repository (eg text or ini file, in the registary etc), or in an [CustomXmlPart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customxmlparts)

Answer (score -1):

To get this done with the original colour of the cell (as per comments) is a lot more complicated than you've done in your example (setting it back to xlnone). The following sub with accompanying function will do the trick for any RGB colour available.

```
Public rngcolor As Range
Public rngcolor2 As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not rngcolor Is Nothing Then
            If Not rngcolor2 = "" Then
                If rngcolor2 = 16777215 Then
                    rngcolor.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                    Else
                    rngcolor.Interior.Color = rngcolor2
                End If
            End If
    End If
    Set rngcolor = Target
    rngcolor2 = Color(Target)
    rngcolor.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

The function getting the RGB colour form the cell: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24216193/11936678))

```
Function Color(rng As Range, Optional formatType As Integer = 0) As Variant
    Dim colorVal As Variant
    colorVal = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Interior.Color
    Select Case formatType
        Case 1
            Color = Hex(colorVal)
        Case 2
            Color = (colorVal Mod 256) & ", " & ((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256) & ", " & (colorVal \ 65536)
        Case 3
            Color = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Interior.ColorIndex
        Case Else
            Color = colorVal
    End Select
End Function
```

This stores the original cell and original colour as an RGB value in a public variable, and resets the deselected cell to these values.

Please note, if multiple cells are selected at once, their interior colour will be reset to that of the first cell in the selection.

Also note the value 16777215 is for RGB white, the default cell colour, equal to xlNone. If the exception for this is left out, the cell will be filled with white, instead of being reset to no colour. If you have cells specifically coloured white, omit this step.