# Excel - Conditionally format .DataLabel property on chart based on value in data table

Tags: excel, vba, object, charts, formatting

I have tried to do this with both VBA and adding multiple data series, but I think because of my chart type I have to use VBA.  I am using this template: https://templates.office.com/en-au/project-timeline-with-milestones-tm00000009.  On the table of data I have added an additional column "category" which contains one of five different categories that the particular "milestone" falls into.  I have formatted the data labels on the chart to have a fill color behind them, and I would like to be able to have that color changed based on what category the milestone is in from the table.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this: https://chandoo.org/wp/conditional-formatting-chart-data-labels/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I did try this in my initial research; however, it doesn't work on this chart type as I cannot add multiple series.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code's comments and customize it to fit your needs

[image]

Place it behind the sheet holding the chart:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Declare object variables
    Dim evalTable As ListObject

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim tableName As String
    Dim categoryColumnNumber As Long
    Dim chartPointNum As Long

    ' Customize to fit your needs
    sheetName = "Project Timeline"
    tableName = "ProjectDetails"
    categoryColumnNumber = 6

    ' Initialize table that holds chart data
    Set evalTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).ListObjects(tableName)

    ' Check if current cell changed belongs to column where categories are defined
    If Not Intersect(Target, evalTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(categoryColumnNumber)) Is Nothing Then

        ' Get the data label number based on cell's position among table
        chartPointNum = Target.Row - evalTable.HeaderRowRange.Row

        ' Set data label background color based on changed cell and it's position
        SetDataLabelColor Target, chartPointNum

    End If

End Sub


Public Sub SetDataLabelColor(TargetCell As Range, chartPointNum As Long)

    Dim evalChart As ChartObject

    Set evalChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Project Timeline")

    With evalChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(chartPointNum).DataLabel.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        ' Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28058868/1521579
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB((TargetCell.Interior.Color Mod 256), ((TargetCell.Interior.Color \ 256) Mod 256), (TargetCell.Interior.Color \ 65536))
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
End Sub
```

If this helps, remember to mark the answer